# How to resize/resample a mask?

Tags: python, image-resizing

If you are familiar with mask, you know that it is like a pixel-wise classifcation ground truth. My question is, how to resize/resample a mask?

For example, a 4x4 array wanted to be resized to a 2x2,

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

0 is the background, 1 is a type of object, 2 is another.

You can't use `nearest` or `bilinear` to resize that right?  Because the boundaries in the mask is clear-cut, and the pixel values are definitely required to be integers. I am wondering what I can use to resize that.

Comment: What you're asking for may not be possible. If you resize the image with the objects that created the mask, some pixels will have parts of multiple objects. Your best bet might be to create multiple masks, one for each object type.

Answer (score 0):

One way of going around this is to apply a 3X3 size filter with a stride of 1X1 over this 4X4 array. Applying the filter on the 4X4 array could be any meaningful operation, such as a majority vote (or take the average and round to closest integer).

Concretely,

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

is translated into

```
majority_vote(array([[1, 1, 0],      majority_vote(array([[1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0],                           [1, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 1]])                          [1, 1, 2]]) 

majority_vote(array([[0, 1, 0],      majority_vote(array([[1, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 1],                           [1, 1, 2],
                     [2, 2, 2]])                          [2, 2, 2]])
```

which results in:

```
array([[1, 0],
        1, 2]])
```

(I resolved ties in majority votes by going with the lower of the two tying numbers)